How to ensure High-Performance CSV to MongoDB Import with Rust: Tokio, Rayon or Alternative Strategies?
I am working on a high-performance data import task where I need to migrate billions of records from CSV files to a MongoDB database. Currently, I'm using Rust and considering the use of Tokio for asynchronous operations to achieve high performance. However, I have several questions and uncertainties about the best approach and strategy:
1. Tokio vs. Rayon:

Given the need for high performance and potentially bulk inserts, would Tokio's asynchronous capabilities be more suitable, or would Rayon be better for parallelism in this scenario?
Are there specific advantages or disadvantages of using one over the other for this type of task?

2. Strategies for CSV Import:

Should I focus on bulk inserts with many async connectors to the database?
What are the best practices for implementing parallelism in Rust for such large-scale data imports?

3. Other case

Let's assume that I need to split each csv files to 10K small files and save them to the local hard disk.
Is it very different from MongoDB migration, in terms of strategies? Because I heard that one thread is better while saving data to hard disk.

I'd greatly appreciate any advice or examples on how to approach this kind of task efficiently and resolve the errors I'm facing. Thank you!
My approaches to the two cases
1. One snippet of the CSV file splitter to local hard disk where I encountered below error.
async fn save_batch_to_file(lines: Vec<String>) -> JoinHandle<Result<(), dyn Error>> {
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        let rect_number = lines.len() / (RECT_SIZE + 1) / RECT_SIZE;

        if !lines.isEmpty() {
            let file_name = format!("file_{}.csv", rect_number);
            let content = lines.join("\n");

            let mut output_file = File::create(file_name).await?;
            output_file.write_all(content.as_bytes()).await?;
            output_file.flush().await?;
        }
        Ok(())
    })
}

I encountered several errors while utilizing tokio::spawn and JoinHandle even though I tried a lot in some ways.

case 1
Error: dyn std::error::Error cannot be sent between threads safely

case 2
Error: the size for values of type dyn std::error::Error cannot be known at compilation time

case 3
Error: ? couldn't convert the error to dyn std::error::Error


2. Another snippet of the code for MongoDB bulk insertion.
Is there any other suggestions to optimize the migration speed?
main.rs
    async fn read_directory(source_folder: &str) -> Result<()> {
    //! Read all the csv files in the directory and parse the csv content into whois records. The
    //! records are then saved to a MongoDB database.
    let paths = std::fs::read_dir(source_folder)?;
    for path in paths {
        // TODO: Check if the file is a csv file
        // Run in parallel
        spawn(async move {
            let path = path.unwrap().path();
            info!("Processing file: {:?}", path);
            if path.is_file() {
                let file_path = path.to_str().unwrap();
                let records = WhoIsRecord::from_file(file_path).unwrap();
                info!("Found {} records in the file {}", records.len(), file_path);
                // Save records into the DB
                WhoIsRecord::save(records).await;
            }
        })
        .await?;
    }
    Ok(())
}

whois.rs
    impl WhoIsRecord {
    /// Read the csv file and return a vector of `WhoIsRecord`
    pub fn from_file(path: &str) -> Result<Vec<Self>> {
        Ok(csv_de(&read_to_string(path)?)?)
    }

    /// Read the csv buffer and return a vector of `WhoIsRecord`
    pub fn from_buffer(buffer: &str) -> Result<Vec<Self>> {
        Ok(csv_de(buffer)?)
    }

    pub async fn save(records: Vec<WhoIsRecord>) {
        //! Save the records to the database.
        let chunked_records = records.chunks(5000).map(|x| x.to_vec()).collect::<Vec<_>>();
        let mut handles = Vec::new();

        info!(
            "Saving {} records to the database. This may take a while...",
            records.len()
        );
        for records in chunked_records {
            let mongo_client_ref = MONGO_CLIENT.clone();
            handles.push(spawn(async move {
                let mongo_client_ref = mongo_client_ref.clone();
                // save the records
                db::upsert(
                    mongo_client_ref.clone(),
                    MONGODB_DB.as_str(),
                    MONGODB_COLLECTION.as_str(),
                    records.to_vec(),
                )
                .await
                .unwrap();
                info!("Saved {} records to the database", records.len());
            }));
        }

        futures::future::join_all(handles).await;
    }
}

/// deserialize the csv text into a vector of `WhoIsRecord`
fn csv_de(csv_text: &str) -> std::result::Result<Vec<WhoIsRecord>, csv::Error> {
    csv::Reader::from_reader(csv_text.as_bytes())
        .deserialize()
        .collect()
}


Tokio primarily makes it easy to keep doing stuff while something else is waiting on some slow I/O (such as the disk or network, eg your database); whereas Rayon primarily makes it easy to parallelise a demanding computation.  The two things are orthogonal, and complementary.  Often you only need one; sometimes you need both.

Did you have a look at mongoimport tool? Why do you like to reinvent the wheel?

First of all, I'd like to learn more about parallelism on certain cases, batch import and bulk insertion, multiple db connectors/clients utilization, etc.
Another important one is that I'm considering about ScyllaDB too.

@WernfriedDomscheit could you please give me any kind of insights?

Have a look at mongoimport. With option numInsertionWorkers > 1 you should be able to get really high insert rates. 10k or 100k documents per second should be feasible.

Except external tools please?
